# Pass credentials using NSURLSession or other iOS method

Tags: ios, objective-c, web, nsurl

I'm trying to login to this [this website](https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/) from an iPhone app, I was thinking I'd use like `NSURLSession` or something because after logging in I was just planning to download the `HTML` using `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`.

How do I pass the credentials (A userpin and password) with my HTML request?

Answer (score 2):

DO you own that website....?

anyway try this
find login request parameter from browser developer tools. There are 3 param here (districtid, Pin, Password)

// create POST request, and send it using NSURLConnection.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/Login"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"districtid=%@&Pin=%@&Password=%@",....pass values here];
NSData * postBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody: postBody];

[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    // do whatever with the data...and errors
    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
    else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
    else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
    else if (error != nil)
}];
```

Comment: It's giving me the error page, here's a test login pin: 20005012 and password: wildcats